# How to place the two modules the way I want?

Tags: module, prestashop

I've managed to create a new hook in the default template of prestashop but I can't place "featured products" under "image slider" (see image to understand what I mean).

http://oi59.tinypic.com/15s95oy.jpg

I've added a segment of header.tpl and the place where I've put my div. Do you know what I should change in order to get the final result?

```
        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header" class="grid_9 alpha omega">
            <a id="header_logo" href="{$base_dir}" title="{$shop_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">
                <img class="logo" src="{$logo_url}" alt="{$shop_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if $logo_image_width}width="{$logo_image_width}"{/if} {if $logo_image_height}height="{$logo_image_height}" {/if}/>
            </a>
            <div id="header_right" class="grid_9 omega">
                {$HOOK_TOP}
            </div>

        </div>


        <div id="columns" class="grid_9 alpha omega clearfix">

            <!-- Left -->
            <div id="left_column" class="column grid_2 alpha">
                {$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}
            </div>

            <!-- Center -->
            <div id="center_column" class=" grid_5">

        <div id="myCustomHook"> {hook h='displayTop2'} </div><!--my hook-->
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both "Featured Products" and "Image Slider" are attached to the same hook, you can set their positions within the hook from BackOffice > Modules > Positions.

Comment: the modules are attached to different hooks; "image slider" is on "displayhome" hook and "featuredproducts" is on "displaytop2" hook (I created this hook). I've created a new hook in order to try and place the module under the image and take the space of the entire page, otherwise there will be blank space left.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make this for a better control of position :

```
{hook h='displayTop' mod='slider'}
{hook h='displayTop' mod='homefeat'}
```

Comment: Is this how I should enter your code? or where should I make the changes? ` <div id="center_column" class=" grid_5">{hook h='displayTop' mod='slider'}
   <div id="myCustomHook"> {hook h='displayTop' mod='homefeat'} </div> `